# How do I use a sublist item on my netsuite 1.0 search filter? I tried doing an item.fieldname but it cause an error

Tags: api, netsuite, sublist

I want to get a list or tranids of the custitem1 from items sublist that meet my criteria.

```
var filter = new Array();
filter[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('mainline', null, 'is', 'T');
filter[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('item.custitem1', null, 'is', 'myItems');  // this is not working
var column = new Array();
column[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid');
column[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('createdfrom');
var fulFillSOInternalIDs = nlapiSearchRecord( 'itemfulfillment', null, filter, column);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your field doesn't support filtering with "anyof" then you will need to search using expressions. Also, if you are searching for the sublist values you need to have mainline as false cause mainline true only returns body fields. Here's how it works:

```
var columns = [];
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn("tranid"));
columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn("createdfrom"));

var filters = [];
filters.push(["mainline", "is", "F"]);
filters.push("AND");
//PARENTHESIS START
//Looping through myItems array to create the expression
var parens = [];
for (var i in myItems){
    parens.push(["item.custitem1", "is", myItems[i]]);
    parens.push("OR");
}
parens.pop();//Remove the last OR
filters.push(parens);
//PARENTHESIS END

var transactionSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("itemfulfillment", null, filters, columns);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should join your filter. insert the filter below in @adolfos' code.

```
filter[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('custitem1', 'item', 'is', 'myItems');
```